# Recursive Word Checking in Python

Tags: python, recursion

Trying to check if a word can be made from a list of characters. It should return the word if it is able to be made from the letters in rack, and a blank string if it cannot. I get the error, `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`.

```
def checkWord(rack,word,hold):
    if word == "": return hold
    if rack[0] == []: return ""
    if rack[0] == word[0]: return checkWord(rack[1:], word[1:], hold)
    return checkWord(rack[1:] + rack[0], word, hold)
print(checkWord(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"], "am", "am"))
```

Comment: I guess rack[0] is a str and not a list, and you are trying to add it to rack[1:]

Comment: (you are saving space with oneline if/return, but not so much readability)

Comment: As an aside, you know you can do this better *non*-recursively, right? Assuming this isn't an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot concatenate a list with a string, so you have to use strings for both, or lists for both , try this

```
def checkWord(rack,word,hold):
    if word == "": return hold
    if rack[0] == []: return ""
    if rack[0] == word[0]: return checkWord(rack[1:], word[1:], hold)
    return checkWord(str(rack[1:]) + str(rack[0]), word, hold)
print(checkWord(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"], "am", "am"))
```

or this

```
def checkWord(rack,word,hold):
    if word == "": return hold
    if rack[0] == []: return ""
    if rack[0] == word[0]: return checkWord(rack[1:], word[1:], hold)
    return checkWord(list(rack[1:]) + list(rack[0]), word, hold)
print(checkWord(["a", "s", "m", "t", "p"], "am", "am"))
```

Answer (score 0):

A [bhansa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3950422/bhansa) commented, your issue is with concatenating `rack[1:]` and `rack[0]`. If `rack` is a list, then so is the slice `rack[1:]`. However, `rack[0]` will be a single value from the list. You probably want to replace `rack[0]` with `[rack[0]]` (creating a new list with a single item) or `rack[:1]` (slicing one item from the list).

It's worth noting that your original code would have worked (at least, that part of it would) if your input for `rack` was a string. That's because strings are an odd kind of container, as both indexing and slicing give you another string.

A final note: Your base case `if rack[0] == []: return ""` will never run with the input you show. It looks to see if the first item in the `rack` list is another list. Since you're passing a list of characters (and only rearranging them in the recursive calls), that will never be true. It *could* work if you passed in a `rack` list with a special sentenel value added to the end (so you can tell when you've fully rotated your original list). But that's not what you're doing. That approach would also mess up the other recursive case (since it doesn't have any way to move the empty list sentinel back to the end after it's matched a character).

Answer (score 0):

```
def checkWord(rack,word,hold):
    try:
        if word == "": return hold
        if rack[0] == []: return ""
        if rack[0] == word[0]: return checkWord(rack[1:], word[1:], hold)
        return checkWord(str(rack[1:]) + str(rack[0]), word, hold)
    except:
        print('it cant')

checkWord(['a','c','b'],'ac','ac') ## return ac
checkWord(['a','c','b'],'dac','dac') ## return It cant
```

but i think this is obfuscating an error, your function either return true, or get stuck in an infinity loop ( if the rack doesn't contain the letters), 
it should check if letter is in hold -> store -> check if got all letters -> if got return hold word, else continue loop until end

instead of checking word[0] and return word[1:], than later this way
You also forgot to add a "can't form word" without trowing an exception

Comment: Using `str(rack[1:])` is almost certainly wrong. If `rack` is a list, calling `str` on it will give you a string like `"['c', 'b']"` with brackets and all. I think either the *calling* code needs to be changed to use strings, or you can stick with lists throughout and only the second part of the concatenation needs changing.

Comment: that's not the only thing wrong, i talked about how the code doesn't do what he expected to do, and how to fix it, and leave to him choose if he wanted my to give a better explanation, i just did some minimal changes to the code he wrote run